# Merge PDF from outputStream

Tags: pdf, itext

I have two PDF files, each one in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I want to merge the two PDFs, and I want to use iText, but i don't understand how can I make it because it use only InputStream. Who can help me?

Answer (score 4):

The `ByteArrayOutputStream` object has a [`toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29) method that returns a `byte[]`. The `PdfReader` class has a [constructor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#PdfReader%28byte%5B%5D%29) that takes a byte[] as parameter. Once you have a `PdfReader` instance of both files, you can use these instances with `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` to merge the files. Use the [Concatenate](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123) example for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code snippet in addition to @Lowagie's answer. This function reads a input pdf and writes to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and creates a second Pdf in another `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Once done with both Pdf it uses the `byte[]` from both stream by calling their `toByteArray()` and uses it to create new `PdfReader`.

```
private void mergeTwoPdf() {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(os);
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/input.pdf"))));
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

        // ... some process on pdf

        pdf.close();

        //Preparing to create final merged pdf
        PdfWriter resultWriter = new PdfWriter("/tmp/output.pdf");
        PdfDocument resultPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(resultWriter);

        // Create new PdfReader & PdfDocument from OutputStream of first pdf
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));
        PdfDocument pdfDoc1 = new PdfDocument(reader);

        // Copy pages of first PdfDocument to Final PdfDocument
        pdfDoc1.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDoc1.getNumberOfPages(), resultPdfDoc);

        // Preparing to create Second PdfDocument in memory stream.
        ByteArrayOutputStream os2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer2 = new PdfWriter(os2);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc2 = new PdfDocument(writer2);

        // Some dummy operation on second Pdf
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc2, new PageSize(pdfDoc1.getFirstPage().getPageSizeWithRotation()));
        document.add(new Paragraph("This is a demo text"));
        document.close();

        // Create new PdfReader & PdfDocument from OutputStream of second PdfDocument
        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(os2.toByteArray()));
        PdfDocument toAttach = new PdfDocument(reader2);

        // Copy pages of second PdfDocument to Final PdfDocument
        toAttach.copyPagesTo(1, toAttach.getNumberOfPages(), resultPdfDoc);

        resultPdfDoc.close();
        pdfDoc1.close();
        toAttach.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```